# Remove a specific value from a key (HashMaps)

Tags: java, hashmap, key

I have the following HashMap (`HashMap<String, String[]>`) and was wondering, if there is a method to remove a specific String from the array of a specific key.

I've found only methods to remove one key basing on a value, but for example, I have:

```
("key1", new String[]{"A", "B", "C"})
```

How can I remove only B?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for using `String[]`, rather than some sort of `Collection<String>`? It'd be much easier then: arrays aren't designed to have elements removed easily (not least, they are fixed length).

Answer (score 2):

Here's s plain Java solution:

```
map.computeIfPresent("key1", (k, v) -> Arrays.stream(v)
  .filter(s -> !s.equals("B")).toArray(String[]::new));
```

Comment: Nice usage of the new Java 8 elements! But note that you need Java 8 for this to work.

Comment: @Zabuza well Java 8 has been out now for well over 2 years. It's mainstream now. If someone is forced to use Java 7 then they really should remove the cause (upgrade/ditch their ancient container, etc) and rejoin the modern world.

Answer (score 0):

You would get the values for the specific key and remove the given value from it, then put it back into the map.

```
public void <K> removeValueFromKey(final Map<K, K[]> map, final K key, final K value) {
    K[] values = map.get(key);
    ArrayList<K> valuesAsList = new ArrayList<K>(values.length);
    for (K currentValue : values) {
        if (!currentValue.equals(value)) {
            valuesAsList.add(currentValue);
        }
    }

    K[] newValues = new K[valuesAsList.size()];
    newValues = valuesAsList.toArray(newValues);
    map.put(key, newValues);
}
```

Be aware that the runtime of course is linear to the size of the given **array**. There is no faster way, because you need to iterate over each element of the array to find all values that are equal to the given value.

However, you could do a faster implementation with other data structures, if that is practicable. For example **sets** would be better than **arrays**, or any other data structure that implements `contains` is faster than O(n).

The same holds for space complexity; you have a peak where you need to hold both arrays in the memory. This is because the size of an array cannot be changed; the method will construct a new array. Thus you will have two arrays in the memory, `O(2n)`.

A `Collection<String>` may be a better solution, depending on how often you'll call the method, compared to how many elements a **map** holds.

Another thing is that you can speed up the progress by guessing a good initial capacity for the **ArrayList**.

Comment: Which `ArrayUtils` class are you referring to? I don't know of such a class in standard Java.

Comment: Oh, I'm very sorry. Of course you are right. You need to create a new array manually. But as you do not know the new size without iterating over all elements first, the best would be to use a fast list object as placeholder. For example a `LinkedList<String>`. I'll edit my first answer.